# Google Analytics event on a click to call button - Not working

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, click-tracking

I am trying to track button clicks with Universal Google analytics event tracking code but cannot for the life of me get the events to show up in my Google Analytics account.

```
<a href="tel:+1-<?php $ringpool->number(); ?>" onclick-ga('send', 'event', 'ButtonClicks', 'ClickedButton1', 'CallAttempt');"><div style="font-size: 29px; text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #015b2d; background: #0096d9 none repeat scroll 0% 0%; width: 100%;  border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000; width: 100%; padding: 5px 0; text-align: center;">Call: <?php $ringpool->number(); ?></div></a>
```

Could someone take a look at my code and let me know what I could possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: "onclick-ga" - is this a typo in your question ? Because that's not the proper syntax to add an onclick event  (if you must add this inline you'd do it like onclick="ga('send'....) )

Comment: No it was not a typo in my question, it was an error in the code. Thanks for your answer. Problem solved!